# External Mysql login on Owncloud

Tags: php, mysql, owncloud

I have a server running on my raspberry pi server. I have made a login page and I've installed owncloud on it. Owncloud and the server login page are using mysql to login, but both of them have 2 different login pages. How do i convert the owncloud login to the external login page? I want to keep owncloud password, but to make it autologin to owncloud when you login to the main website.

Comment: Does this really make sense? If you automatically log in to OwnCloud as soon as you log in to your external login page (i.e. you redirect from your external login page to OwnCloud), what do you need the external login page for? Do you just want to customize the OwnCloud login page that way?

Comment: I have a website on my website and now, I want add a server, so i could connect a hdd to it,  but i want to keep the website and all of its contents and have a button to redirect to a server if i need to. Right now, if i go to the server i have to login to it too, I have tried to mess around with owncloud files, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your external login page takes the credentials and does a redirect to the nextcloud login page with login and password as post parameters. This should work just fine.
By the way. Please use nextcloud instead of owncloud because it is fully open source, faster and has more features
Nextcloud login page can also be fully customized so maybe you don’t need the first login page at all

Comment: I have tried nextcloud, but it was very slow and barely useable, because I'm tyring to run the server on a raspberry pi B. Owncloud seems to be a bit faster. I will try to do as you say and install nextcloud, but i still don't get how to 'autologin', but i will try to when i install it

Comment: I have installed nextcloud and I'm sorry for being such a noob, but I cannot set it up by myself, because i don't understand it...